# Can't factory reset my Pentax K-70 DSLR

Tags: dslr, camera-settings, pentax

So I'm pretty sure I've jacked up my camera for good and I don't know what I did wrong so I want to factory reset it, but when I go to the "Reset" option, it is grayed out. When I go to the "Factory Reset" option, it is also grayed out. I've looked online and I can't find any articles about enabling factory reset. It's a Ricoh camera by the way. Pretty new. Been able to shoot it a few times. Everything always looks terrible so I'm hoping to go back. It's gotten to the point where photos are 100% pure black on two different lenses on all but one of the camera modes and all photos are always super grainy, even when I adjust F, +/-, and ISO. I'd be curious as to why these other problems exist, but what I really need is the factory restore to be enabled. Part of what this could be is I'm using SLR lenses from the 80's, but that doesn't explain why I can't do a factory restore. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the old - take ALL the batteries out (including the one for date/time persistence etc) and turn on/off a few times before putting batteries back in? This can help purge residual charge from capacitors etc that allow the processors inside to retain settings. Incidentally have you seen [this thread](https://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/151-pentax-k-30-k-50/315725-dark-exposure-problems-k-30-k-50-discussion-thread.html)?